# Does interval spacing effect Hausdorff dimension of Cantor set?

Tags: fractals, geometric-measure-theory, dimension-theory-analysis

Let $C=\bigcap_{j=0}^{2^n}C_j$, $C_0=[0,1]$, and the intervals in the construction of each stage of $C_j$ consists of removing the center 1/3 from the $j-1$ stage intervals.  In other words, the Cantor middle third set.  The dimension of this set is known to be $\frac{\log 2}{\log 3}$.  Now consider the following adjustment: we now only require allow the spacing between the intervals at each stage, $j$, to be disjoint. That is, we only require spacing between intervals to be >0. It is clear to me, from the definition of Hausdorff dimension that interval spacing should not affect an upper bound calculation on a Cantor Set.

My question is this: Can changing the nonnegative spacing between intervals cause the lower bound calculation to diverge from the upper bound calculation in the context of Cantor sets? For sets in general? If yes for the Cantor sets, can someone direct me to a lower bound technique that explicitly incorporates spacing. If yes only for sets in general, what about Cantor sets makes spacing irrelavant?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Update: [see the other answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1629775)

---

You will not be able to get the same lower bound, and for a good reason. Reduced spacing between the remaining 1/3-intervals can make the Hausdorff dimension of the Cantor-type set arbitrarily small. Intuitively, this is because when the intervals are placed nearby, they can be covered more efficiently. Here is a more precise argument.

Fix $s>0$; I will build a Cantor-type set of $s$-dimensional Hausdorff measure zero. To do this, I will arrange to  have a sequence of scales $\delta_j\to 0$ such that generation $m_j$ of the construction can be covered by $N_j$ intervals of size $\delta_j$, with $N_j \delta_j^s\le 1/j$.

For $j=1$ I can take $\delta_1=N_1=1$, which cover the $0$th generation $(m_j=0)$ of the Cantor-type set, namely $[0,1]$. Suppose now that $N_j$, $\delta_j$, $m_j$ are already arranged.

I have $2^{m_j}$ intervals in the $m_j$-generation. Let $N_{j+1}=2^{m_j}$ and choose $\delta_{j+1}$ so that  $N_{j+1} \delta_{j+1}^s\le 1/(j+1)$.

For each of the aforementioned $2^{m_j}$ intervals, repeat the process of replacing the interval by two intervals of $1/3$ its length and leaving only a **tiny** gap between them: after sufficiently many such steps the resulting set will be contained in $\frac12\delta_{j+1}$-neighborhood of the midpoint of the original interval. At this moment I have generation $m_{j+1}$ of the Cantor-type set, which is covered by $N_{j+1}$ intervals of length $\delta_{j+1}$, as desired.

Comment: Very illuminating.  Thank you.  A follow up question might be, does spacing effect the actual Hausdorff Dimension, or just the lower bound?

Comment: @user148106 The actual Hausdorff dimension, which is what my post shows.

Comment: Forgive me, as I am new to this topic, but doesn't an $s$-dimensional Hausdorff measure=0 imply an upper bound on the  Hausdorff dimension?  When looking for a lower bound, aren't we looking for an $s$ such that our $s$-dimensional Hausdorff measure is >0? Or does your argument imply that we will have $s$-dimensional Hausdorff measure=0 for all $s>0$ (implying that the Hausdorff dimension=0 for all $s$)?

Comment: The standard Cantor set has Hausdorff dimension $\log 2/\log 3$. I show that for any given $s>0$, one can change the spacing to make Hausdorff dimension $\le s$. This implies (by choosing $s<\log 2/\log 3$) that the Hausdorff dimension can indeed be changed by changing the spacing. I did not attempt to calculate the actual dimension for the construction I outlined. But it can be made $0$ by replacing $N_j \delta_j^s\le 1/j$ with something like $N_j \log(1/\delta_j) \le 1/s$.

Comment: The one part of your argument which I cant get past is "after sufficiently many such steps the resulting set will be contained in $\frac{1}{2}\delta _{j+1}$-neighborhood of the midpoint of the original interval". Since $\delta_j$ is going to zero, doesn't this claim amount to saying the resulting set is a point? This can't be the case, can it?

Comment: No, it does not amount to that. I say that for each of the $2^{m_j}$ intervals ... after sufficiently many steps, what remains is contained in a small neighborhood of the midpoint of that interval. My last comment here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17658/discussion-between-user148106-and-care-bear).

Comment: As indicated in the other answer, this argument is incorrect.  The problem is that once you've taken one of your $2^{m_j}$ intervals and chosen two subintervals twice, you now have four subintervals, and the leftmost of these four must be at least $2\epsilon$ away from the rightmost, where $\epsilon=3^{-m_j-2}$ is the length of these subintervals.  As a result, no matter how many more times you choose smaller subintervals, you will still have points that are at least distance $2\epsilon$ apart.

Answer (score 5):

I regret having to note that the other answer is wrong. It is well known, since work of Moran in 1946, that the Hausdorff dimension of the particular set that you describe does not depend on the location of the intervals at each step. For a proof you can see the book Dimension and Recurrence in Hyperbolic Dynamics, by Barreira (see Theorem 3.1.1).

Comment: Since asking this question I have since understood, through studying Moran sets incidentally, why the first answer can not be true. My current understanding is that the placement of intervals can only change the dimension of the set when the infimum of the contraction ratios (determined at each level) is 0 .  The dimension of the Cantor set obviously does not meet this condition therefore cannot be affected by interval placement.

Comment: Sure, I understand that the question is from long ago. :-) It is exactly as you describe. But, don't mind me saying, but then you really shouldn't keep as accepted an answer that you know is wrong.